# Unnest and Pivot Longer with Duplicate Columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a nested `df` that I am trying to clean up.

```
Sample Data:
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
  ~idTeam, ~ptsTotalBehindFirst, ~ptsOverall, ~ptsDiffLastPeriod, ~rankOverall, ~ptsBattingBehindFirst, ~ptsBatting, ~ptsDiffBattingLastPeriod,                                                                                                                                                                            ~dataBatting, ~rankBatting, ~ptsPitchingBehindFirst, ~ptsPitching, ~ptsDiffPitchingLastPeriod,                                                                                                                                                                                                   ~dataPitching, ~rankPitching,
      "2",                  "0",       "111",               "-4",           1L,                    "0",        "65",                       "0", list(abbr = c("OBP", "HR", "RBI", "R", "SB"), roto_points = c(13, 13, 13, 13, 13), value = c(0.3663, 384, 1012, 1102, 164), diff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rank = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),           1L,                     "5",         "46",                       "-4",                            list(abbr = c("S", "W", "K", "ERA", "WHIP"), roto_points = c(12, 6, 11, 8, 9), value = c(94, 89, 1576, 3.946, 1.2179), diff = c(0, -2, -2, 0, 0), rank = c(2, 8, 3, 6, 5)),            3L,
      "8",               "13.5",      "97.5",                "2",           2L,                   "13",        "52",                       "0",    list(abbr = c("OBP", "HR", "RBI", "R", "SB"), roto_points = c(12, 11, 11, 12, 6), value = c(0.3576, 323, 954, 1011, 89), diff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), rank = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 8)),           3L,                   "5.5",       "45.5",                        "2", list(abbr = c("S", "W", "K", "ERA", "WHIP"), roto_points = c(2, 7.5, 10, "13", 13), value = c(56, 91, 1508, 3.688, 1.1474), diff = c(-1, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 0), rank = c(12, 6, 4, 1, 1)),            4L
  )
```

The data I am trying to `unnest` is stored in the `dataBatting` and `dataPitching` columns.  I am trying to `unnest` all of the columns in both columns and bind the results as rows. Something akin to `pivot_longer` but I wasn't sure of the right way to do this with 4 duplicate columns nested within 2 separate columns.

My attempt to do this was:

```
  df %>% 
  unnest_wider(dataBatting) %>% 
  unnest(c(abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank)) %>% 
  unnest_wider(dataPitching) %>% 
  unnest(c(abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank))
```

```
Error is:
Error: Column names `abbr`, `roto_points`, `value`, `diff`, `rank` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

My issue is that I want to bind the same columns from dataPitching that have the same column names as dataBatting (abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank).

I also want to change the name of the columns that are duplicates.  Is `tidyr::hoist` a better way to do this?

Desired `df`:

```
tibble::tribble(
                                              ~idTeam, ~ptsTotalBehindFirst, ~ptsOverall, ~ptsDiffLastPeriod, ~rankOverall, ~ptsBattingBehindFirst, ~ptsBatting, ~ptsDiffBattingLastPeriod,  ~abbr, ~roto_points5, ~value, ~diff, ~rank, ~rankPitching, ~ptsPitchingBehindFirst, ~ptsPitching, ~ptsDiffPitchingLastPeriod,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,  "OBP",            13, 0.3663,     0,     1,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,   "HR",            13,    384,     0,     1,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,  "RBI",            13,   1012,     0,     1,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,    "R",            13,   1102,     0,     1,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,   "SB",            13,    164,     0,     1,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,    "S",            12,     94,     0,     2,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,    "W",             6,     89,    -2,     8,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,    "K",            11,   1576,    -2,     3,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0,  "ERA",             8,  3.946,     0,     6,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    2,                    0,         111,                 -4,            1,                      0,          65,                         0, "WHIP",             9, 1.2179,     0,     5,             3,                       5,           46,                         -4,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,  "OBP",            12, 0.3576,     0,     2,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,   "HR",            11,    323,     0,     3,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,  "RBI",            11,    954,     0,     3,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,    "R",            12,   1011,     0,     2,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,   "SB",             6,     89,     0,     8,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,    "S",             2,     56,    -1,    12,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,    "W",           7.5,     91,   1.5,     6,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,    "K",            10,   1508,   0.5,     4,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0,  "ERA",            13,  3.688,     1,     1,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2,
                                                    8,                 13.5,        97.5,                  2,            2,                     13,          52,                         0, "WHIP",            13, 1.1474,     0,     1,             4,                     5.5,         45.5,                          2
                                              )
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error with the example you showed. `df %>% unnest(c(dataBatting, dataPitching))#
# A tibble: 10 x 15`

Comment: Fixed this as I realize my example wasn't clear.

Comment: It is still working fine  `df %>% 
+   unnest_wider(dataBatting) %>%  unnest(c(abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank))
# A tibble: 10 x 19` not getting any error

Comment: I added more information to make clearer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: The issue is also related to no common type

Comment: e.g. Check the type here `df %>% unnest_wider(dataPitching) %>% as.data.frame %>% .$roto_points`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to loop through the 'dataBatting', 'dataPitching' column names, do the `unnest_wider` separately, `unnest` the columns of interest, and bind the rows together (`map_dfr` - suffix 'dfr' returns dataframe with rows binded together from a `list` of `data.frames` of `tibble`s).  One thing that should be noted is that many of the tidyverse functions are type sensitive.  Here, we find some `list` elements to have different types and this would have an issue in `unnest` unless the 'ptype' is mentioned.  To avoid that, we can use `type.convert` to change the type automatically based on the values and then do the `unnest`ing

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfr(c('dataBatting', 'dataPitching'), ~ 
         df %>% 
           unnest_wider(.x) %>%
           mutate_at(vars(c(abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank)), 
                    type.convert) %>% 
           unnest(c(abbr, roto_points, value, diff, rank)) %>% 
           mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
           select(-one_of(c("dataBatting", "dataPitching"))))
```

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  What does the type.convert in the mutate do?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz. If you notice some of the `list` elements, they have different `types` `roto_points` causing issue while `unnest`ing otherwise you need to specify the `ptype` argument.  I didn't want to do that because it would be more manual